# representing graph attributes in C

Tags: c, algorithm, graph

I've been reading up on graph algorithms, which make perfect sense in pseudo-code.
Implementing them in C, however, has raised some issues I can't seem to remedy easily;

So many graph algorithms rely on colourings or other ad-hoc attributes assigned to verities and/or edges .. but how can I implement this *inside* an algorithm (i.e. not have to make changes to the graph representation (which is a form of adjacency lists))?

The main issue here stems from the fact that as I traverse the graph via adjacency lists, the vertexes they reference contain no linkage back to any auxiliary data structure I create to hold the attributes! Thus resulting in having to performs additional searches which may alter the computational complexity of some of these algorithms

I'm sure someone else has come across this issue in C and figured out a clever way..

Comment: So... what is your question again?

Comment: Vertices are easier than edges/arcs: in many cases you can just use an array for each vertex attribute. For edges, the best approach would probably vary from algorithm to algorithm.

Comment: @sashoalm: To quote the question: "how can I implement this inside an algorithm (...)?" To my eye, the question is pretty clear and unambiguous, and is better presented than the vast majority of questions asked on this site.

Comment: @NPE but how do I index into these arrays? Say I'm traversing my graph, and grab a vertex referenced from some adjacency list. How can I use said vertex to determine it's attributes stored in these auxiliary arrays?

Comment: Yeah, that's tricky if you don't have any natural indexing. Maybe your vertex structure should have an index as one of the fields? If that's not practical, you're probably looking at a hash map from pointers to integers (vertex indices) just to establish vertex indexing.

Comment: Or, to extend that, a hash map from vertex pointers to auxiliary attributes required by the algorithm.

Comment: @NPE ya thats what I was thinking I'd have to do since there isn't any natural indexing really. What are your 2 cents on storying a dummy (void *) buffer/flex field within each vertex for attaching arbitrary attributes? With, of course, the understanding this field is meaningless outside context of an algorithm and can freely be overwritten

Comment: I would put a extra field to vertex as the simplest solution. Unless of course you are really badly space limited in which case you have to do something more complex in any case. More complex might be even having only part of graph loaded at a time.

But pointer has down side that how do you know if it was set by current algorithm run or previous algorithm run. It might be easier to assign unique index for eat vertex and use that to access extra data stored in a array.

Comment: @PauliNieminen ya, subroutines inside algorithms would be a problem. It seems like managing unique index's in the vertex rep may be the best choice..